# ¿Como saber que palabra esta repetida y sacar contador?

Tags: java

Hasta el momento solo tengo Esto que solo me muestra la palabra mas repetida necesito saber como poder obtener
A=2, L=1, E=2, X=1

He intentado encontrar la validación correcta pero aun no lo logro podrían ayudarme gracias

```
String ValidateWord="ALEXANDER";
String[] validate;

for(int r = 0; r < ValidateWord.length(); r++){
validate =  ValidateWord.split("");
     for(int g = 0; g < ValidateWord.length(); g++){
        if(validate[r].equals(validate[g])){
            System.out.println(validate[r]+ validate[g]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar equals? ¿Es un ejercicio de clase? ¿Que problema tienes? Veo que no has realizado el [tour] de StackOverflow, te invito a hacerlo y de paso, recibir tu primera medalla. A su vez te invito a pasar por [ask] para ver como elaborar una buena pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida.

Comment: Es un Ejecicio si utilize equals pero sigo sin resultados

Comment: ¿Puedes detallar más? ¿La idea es ver las palabras repetidas en un `String[]`?

Comment: Veras asi como lo vez ya te aparece la palabra que se repite mas el problema es cuando quieres obtener el conteo de esas palabras pero dividias en secciones si vez tenemos 2 LETRAS A 1 LETRA L Y 2 LETRAS E y 1 LETRA X=1 las cuales tienen que printar al momento de mandarlas

A=2, L=1, E=2, X=1

Comment: ¿Para que quieres dividir cada letra de la palabra en distintas posiciones de un Array?

Comment: Por ahora lo unico que puedo obtener es la palabra mas repetida disculpa la letra mas repetida

Comment: ¿Entonces necesitas la letra o la palabra repetida?

Comment: No la letra o palabra ya la consigo lo que necesito es obtener solo esto  A=2, L=1, E=2, X=1 pero necesito adaptarlo a mi codigo para obtenerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que euieres es mostrar la letra que más se repite y cuantas veces se repite, entonces lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

```
String validateWorld = "ALEXANDER";
        String cadena[];
        int cont = 0;
        int max = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < validateWorld.length(); i++){
            for(int r = 0; r < validateWorld.length(); r++) {
                cont = 0;
                cadena = validateWorld.split("");
                if(cadena[i].equals(cadena[r])) {

                }
                for(int j = 0; j < validateWorld.length(); j++){
                    if(String.valueOf(validateWorld.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(validateWorld.charAt(j)))){
                        cont ++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(cont > max) {
                max=cont;
                System.out.println(validateWorld.charAt(i)+"  is the word more repeated with "+ max+ " times.");
            }
        }
```

Si esto es lo que buscabas desde el principio al menos ya me quedó claro lo que querías, tambien te recomiendo que te aclares más en tus futuras preguntas. Espero que te sirva :D

Answer (score 2):

No sé si te valdrá mi solución pero creo que se acerca a lo que quieres hacer.

```
package Java;
import java.util.*;

public class LetraRepetida {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String validateWorld,worldNoSpace;
        int cont;

        System.out.println("Introduce una cadena de carácteres: ");
        validateWorld=sc.nextLine();
        worldNoSpace = validateWorld.trim();
        for(int i = 0; i < worldNoSpace.length(); i++){
            cont = 0;
            //validate =  ValidateWord.split("");
            for(int j = 0; j < worldNoSpace.length(); j++){
                if(String.valueOf(worldNoSpace.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(worldNoSpace.charAt(j)))){
                    cont ++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("La letra "+worldNoSpace.charAt(i)+" se ha repetido en ésta cadena "+ cont+ " veces.");
        }
    }

}
```

Por ejemplo, si le metes "Alejandro" como nombre lo que te devolverá será:

- La letra A se ha repetido en ésta cadena 2 veces.
- La letra l se ha repetido en ésta cadena 1 veces.
- La letra e se ha repetido en ésta cadena 1 veces.
- La letra j se ha repetido en ésta cadena 1 veces.
- La letra a se ha repetido en ésta cadena 2 veces.
- La letra n se ha repetido en ésta cadena 1 veces.
- La letra d se ha repetido en ésta cadena 1 veces.
- La letra r se ha repetido en ésta cadena 1 veces.
- La letra o se ha repetido en ésta cadena 1 veces.
  Espero que te sirva de base para conseguir lo que quieres hacer. :D

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu codigo si lo pude adaptar vere si meterle un trim pueda quitarme los espacio o quitarme alguna leta mil gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Quieres asegurarte de que el usuario no meta un nombre con espacios por delante y por detras ,no?

Comment: E modificado la respuesta para asegurarse de que no tenga espacios por delante y por detrás, si te sirve con ésta última modificación te agradecería mucho que le dieras el tic. :D

Comment: Veras si esta super solo que quiero remover y dejar solo  A=2, L=1, E=2, X=1 ya lo trate de implementar incluso con trimp y split pero sigo sin lograrlo lo seguire si encuentro la respuesta igual la posteare

Comment: Quieres que en pantalla se vea asi?
A = 2
L =1
E =2
X =1
No me queda muy claro lo que quieres ':)

Comment: Creme que el ejecicio como a ti no me quedo tampoco muy claro pero pues espero que al adaptarlo con mi codigo funcione ya lo adapte solo necesito mostrar la palabra mas repetida